# Google Cloud DataStore GQL

Tags: gql

I am developing an adapter for waterline on NODEJS, I'm implementing the interface adapter but I have a problem to describe schema for google cloud datastore, I need to get the list of properties of a kind but I don't know how to get the properties. I have tried this SQL but only I get the kinds without the properties.

```
select __key__ from __kind__
```

How is the equivalent of Mysql describe on GQL?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who wants to get all the properties of a kind, the query is so easy. the next code is the example of the kind, the name of the kind is Task.

example of the creation of the kind

```
const kind = 'Task';
const name = '100';

const taskKey = datastore.key([kind, name]);

const task = {
  key: taskKey,
  data: {
    description: 'not more tasks',
  }
};

datastore
  .save(task)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('the creation ends fine');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('ERROR:', err);
  });
```

example of the query that returns the properties of the kinds

```
select * from __Stat_PropertyName_Kind__ where kind_name = 'Task'
```

example of NODEJS code that returns and prints the properties of a kind

```
const query = datastore
      .createQuery('__Stat_PropertyName_Kind__')
      .filter('kind_name', '=', 'Task');

datastore.runQuery(query).then(results => {
        var response = results[0];
        var schema = response[0];
        console.log(schema.kind_name);
        console.log(schema.property_name);
    });
```

the result of the query are the next:
Task
description